# 'homecntrl' is not a function, got undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test my controller .I am able to make simple controller in angular js and able to test controller online .here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/xzvhXHPoUdulOM9clOkQ?p=preview

**controller code**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app.home').controller('homeCntrl',homeCntrl);

  function homeCntrl(){
    var home=this;
    home.clickbtn=function(){

      home.message='test';
      alert(home.message)
    }
  }
})();
```

but when test in my **pc**  it not run and getting this error

```
**Argument 'homecntrl' is not a function, got undefined
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=homecntrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
            at /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/SimpleDemo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12**
```

here is my code of **test**

```
(function(){

    'use strict'
    describe('http controller test', function() {

        var $rootScope,
            $scope,
            controller,
            $q,
            $httpBackend;

        beforeEach(function() {
            module('app');

            inject(function($injector) {
                $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                controller = $injector.get('$controller')('homecntrl', {
                    $scope: $scope
                })


            })
        })




        describe('Init value', function() {
            it('check name value', function() {
                expect(controller.message).toBeUndefined();
            })

        })

        it('it should be true', function() {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();

        })
    })


})()
```

I am able to test online but not able to test on pc

here is my code of pc
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/no901z41bza7osm/SimpleDemo.zip?dl=0

please download it and go to project directory and write **npm install**

Answer (score 0):

You should update your controller name `homeCntrl` to `homecntrl`

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app.home').controller('homecntrl',homeCntrl);

  function homecntrl(){
    var home=this;
    home.clickbtn=function(){

      home.message='test';
      alert(home.message)
    }
  }
})();
```

It will be work.

Comment: still not working..please download my code and then check